# Getting access of iframe imbedded page elements in js, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```js
document.querySelector('#clickbtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.ytp-large-play-button ytp-button').click();
})
```

```html
<button id="clickbtn">Click</button>


<iframe width="560" height="315" class="clickbtn" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cmA-IyD8_BA" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in- 
    picture" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
```

I'm trying to start playing video from my own created button.
but not working. **Have any solution?**

**console:**

> *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'click') at HTMLButtonElement.*

Comment: _"but not working."_ - you can not access iframe content loaded from a different origin, the Same Origin Policy prevents that. You need to use the functionality YouTube provides via their JS SDK in this specific instance.

Answer (score 0):

use the youtube frame api from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), run/stop the video by

```
function stop() {
  player.stopVideo();
}
```

#### OR

```
function run() {
  player.playVideo();
}
```